# Salvar EditText e DatePicker em Shared Preferences

Tags: android

Estou tentando salvar um edittext e um datepicker mas eles semprem salva os dois com um dado dos dois.
O date Picker ao clicar no Editext2 ele abre o calendario aonde você clica e ele seleciona a data para o edittext2.

só preciso saber como posso salvar os dois ao clicar no botao da activity.

basicamente eu quero salvar a quilometragem do oleo no edittext1, e a data que foi feita no edittext2. o botao ira salvar para mim!

CLASSE OLEO

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Build;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.*;


public class oleo extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {



    private Button buttonSalvarOleo;
    private SharedPreferences savednotes;
    private EditText editTextOleo;
    private EditText editTextData;
    Button buttonOleoRec;


    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_oleo);



        buttonOleoRec = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonOleoRec);
        buttonOleoRec.setOnClickListener(this);

        buttonSalvarOleo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSalvarOleo);
         editTextOleo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextOleo);
         savednotes = getSharedPreferences("notes",MODE_PRIVATE);

        editTextData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextData);


        editTextOleo.setText(savednotes.getString("tag", "00.000")); //adicionar essa linha


        buttonSalvarOleo.setOnClickListener(saveButtonListener);
    }

    //AQUI EH OQUE CHAMA O CALENDARIO
    public void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        EditText editTextData = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextData);
        editTextData.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener(){
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus){
                    DateDialog dialog= new DateDialog(v);
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    dialog.show(ft, "DatePicker");
                }
            }

        });

    }

    private void makeTag(String tag){
        String or = savednotes.getString(tag, null);
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savednotes.edit();
        preferencesEditor.putString("tag",tag); //change this line to this
        preferencesEditor.commit();
    }

    public View.OnClickListener saveButtonListener = new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(editTextOleo.getText().length()>0){
                makeTag(editTextOleo.getText().toString());

                ((InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).hideSoftInputFromWindow(editTextOleo.getWindowToken(),0);

            }


        }
    };

    private void buttonOleoRecClick(){
        //NOME DO LAYOUT Q ESTA NO MANIFEST
        startActivity(new Intent("layout.activity_oleorecomendado"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){
            //fazer pros outros botoes aki
            case R.id.buttonOleoRec:
                buttonOleoRecClick();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

DATEDIALOG CLASSE

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.DialogFragment;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.util.Calendar;

/**
 * Created by Bruno Marna on 9/19/2015.
 */
public class DateDialog  extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    EditText editTextData;
    public DateDialog(View view){
        editTextData=(EditText)view;
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
        int year =c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month=c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day=c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this,year,month,day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day){
        String date=day+"/"+(month+1)+"/"+year;
        editTextData.setText(date);

    }

}
```

ACTIVITY

```
<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:id="@+id/editTextOleo"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Salvar"
        android:id="@+id/buttonSalvarOleo"
        android:layout_weight="1.12"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:background="#444"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextData"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView3" />

<EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editTextData"
        android:hint="dia/mês/ano"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextOleo"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editTextOleo" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Tente o Seguinte:

```
//SALVA OS DADOS:
    //TAG: é o ID para resgatar o valor
    //VALUE: o valor a ser armazenado
    private void makeTag(final String tag, final String value){
        SharedPreferences.Editor preferencesEditor = savednotes.edit();
        /// passamos a TAG, a qual vamos usar para resgatar
        preferencesEditor.putString(tag, value);
        preferencesEditor.commit();
    }
//RESGATA OS DADOS
    //TAG: é o ID para resgatar o valor
    private void getTag(final String tag){
        String value = savednotes.getString(tag, null);
        return value;
    }
```

Para facilitar, sugiro que crie cosntantes com o nome das tags:

```
public final String edittext1TAG = "TAG1";
public final String edittext2TAG = "TAG2";
```

Quando for salvar :

```
makeTag(edittext1TAG, editTextOleo.getText().toString());
```

Saudações,

Comment: Nada ainda :( continua igual... desculpa mas sou novato em programação e fiz essas mudanças mas está igual antes

Comment: Mostre me como fez! não precisa se desculpar! A finalidade deste site é ajudar !  Poste suas alterações para que possamos lhe ajudar!